# ember js non SPA approach

Tags: javascript, ember.js

and I have this wordpress project. I want to make an ember app for specific section of the website like part of the Post page or widget. but I   cant get it to work or missing something. Is it possible for ember like to mount an instance to one div like vuejs can?

appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In the config/environment.js, you can set rootElement to any selector.

For more information, see https://guides.emberjs.com/release/configuring-ember/embedding-applications/

Comment: Oh nice. So there is docs about this, didn't found this one.  This is exactly what im asking. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is essentially [ember-islands](https://github.com/mitchlloyd/ember-islands).